# Counting sub-element in string?

Tags: python, list, string-length

Say I have a `string = "Nobody will give me pancakes anymore"`

I want to count each word in the string. So I do `string.split()` to get a list in order to get `['Nobody', 'will', 'give', 'me', 'pancakes', 'anymore']`.

But when I want to know the length of `'Nobody'` by inputing `len(string[0])` it only gives me `1`, because it thinks that the 0th element is just `'N'` and not `'Nobody'`.

What do I have to do to ensure I can find the length of the whole word, rather than that single element?

Comment: So store the `string.split()` result in a new variable, and take the length of the first element of *that*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm trying that but I get `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

Comment: sounds like you got the syntax for assigning wrong somewhere then. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You took the first letter of `string[0]`, ignoring the result of the `string.split()` call.

Store the split result; that's a list with individual words:

```
words = string.split()
first_worth_length = len(words[0])
```

Demo:

```
>>> string = "Nobody will give me pancakes anymore"
>>> words = string.split()
>>> words[0]
'Nobody'
>>> len(words[0])
6
```

Comment: Oh I got it now! I didn't put the variable in order. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yup, `string[0]` is just `'N'`

Regarding your statement...

> I want to count each word in the string

```
>>> s = "Nobody will give me pancakes anymore"
>>> lens = map(lambda x: len(x), s.split())
>>> print lens
[6, 4, 4, 2, 8, 7]
```

So, then you can do `lens[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
words = s.split()   
d = {word : len(word) for word in words}

or

words = s.split()
d = {}

for word in words:
    if word not in d:
        d[word]=0
    d[word]+=len(word)

In [15]: d  
Out[15]: {'me': 2, 'anymore': 7, 'give': 4, 'pancakes': 8, 'Nobody': 6,   'will': 4}
In [16]: d['Nobody']
Out[16]: 6
```

Comment: So, `d = {word : len(word) for word in words}`? Why the defaultdict?

Comment: Thanks I was trying to write it in a more readable way. I have changed the answer thanks very much for the suggestion.